# Are methods started in a Thread bound to the thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a question, because I am going to develop a simple yet very specialized logging system, other logging systems currently do not fit my needs.

The code:

```
package customlogger;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author student
 */
public class CustomLogger implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private List<LogConsumer> consumers;

    public CustomLogger() {
        this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        this.consumers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String message = queue.take();
                for (LogConsumer consumer : consumers) {
                    consumer.consume(message);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CustomLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void log(String message) {
        queue.offer(message);
    }

    public void addConsumer(LogConsumer consumer) {
        if (consumers.contains(consumer)) {
            return;
        }
        consumers.add(consumer);
    }

    public void removeConsumer(LogConsumer consumer) {
        if (!consumers.contains(consumer)) {
            return;
        }
        consumers.remove(consumer);
    }
}
```

---

```
package customlogger;

/**
 *
 * @author student
 */
public interface LogConsumer {
    public void consume(String message);
}
```

---

```
package customlogger;

/**
 *
 * @author student
 */
public class SystemOutConsumer implements LogConsumer {
    @Override
    public void consume(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

---

Creation code:

```
LogConsumer systemOutConsumer = new SystemOutConsumer();

CustomLogger simpleLogger = new CustomLogger();
simpleLogger.addConsumer(systemOutConsumer);
Thread simpleLoggerThread = new Thread(simpleLogger);
simpleLoggerThread.start();
```

Now assume I want to log a lot of messages with `simpleLogger.log(message);`, will this harm the performance of my program itself?

I run the `CustomLogger` in its own thread so that should not (directly) impact the performance of my program, but is this also the case for the `System.out.println(message)` that is done by the logger?

Comment: If your aim with your custom framework is to achieve asynchronous logging then most frameworks already support that, everything from log4j to log4j2 has asynchronous appenders. I would really consider exactly what it is that you need before taking the plunge.

Comment: It is really bad idea to have a separate thread running for the log. In a multithreaded environment, thread-id helps to find out the related log messages. Thread Id is only one identifier to find out the list of log events in a multithreaded environment. 

All the possible scenarios are mostly covered by the available log frameworks. What is your requirement and what prompted you to write one for your own.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, I have not yet made the specialized parts. This, what I have up till now, is indeed very easily achievable with almost any logging framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not affect performance of your main thread if you do it like this. But I would reconsider using existing logging framework since I don't see that you created anything that's not possible to do with log4j for example ... ...